# jQuery Isotope issues when filtering with a select box and url hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hash

I'm filtering a list of DIVs with Isotope via a select box & URL hash.
I'm using the code example as presented on [the Isotope website examples](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#url-hash)

Please view the code in the JSFiddle below.

In my usecase, the URL hash `filter=` is replaced by `doelgroep=`. Two issues occur.

1. By default, all the items are hidden on page load. I'd like to show everything once the page loads.
2. A JavaScript error occurs every time one navigates directly to a specific url hash. jQuery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=doelgroep=gemeente-of-ocmw]

Could you please help me figure out how to get all the items shown when the page is loaded or nothing `--` is selected? Also, could you please help me figure out the source of this JavaScript error?

Please find the working code on this JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5Ls0q026/

You can also see it in action on its testlocation:
http://curaedis.chocolata.be/diensten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we should go your way then use:

#### Variant №1

```
if($('.items').length) {
    function getHashFilter() {
        var matches = location.hash.match(/doelgroep=([^&]+)/i);
        var hashFilter = matches && matches[1];
        return hashFilter && decodeURIComponent(hashFilter);
    }
    $(function() {
        var $grid = $('.items');
        // bind filter button click
        var $filters = $('#filters').on('change', function() {
            var filterAttr = $(this ).val();
            // set filter in hash
            location.hash = 'doelgroep=' + encodeURIComponent( filterAttr );
        });
        function onHashchange() {
            var hashFilter = getHashFilter() || "*";
            // filter isotope
            $grid.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                filter: hashFilter != "*" ? "." + hashFilter : hashFilter
            });
        }
        $(window).on( 'hashchange', onHashchange );
        // trigger event handler to init Isotope
        onHashchange();
    });
}
```

working copy - https://jsfiddle.net/5Ls0q026/1/

If to go normal way, then you should place dots in your options

#### Variant №2

```
<option value=".zorgverstrekkende-organisatie" 
        data-filter=".zorgverstrekkende-organisatie">zorgverstrekkende organisatie
</option>
```

working copy - https://jsfiddle.net/5Ls0q026/2/

and replace your `onHashchange` function

```
function onHashchange() {
    var hashFilter = getHashFilter();
    // filter isotope
    $grid.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        filter: hashFilter
    });
}
```

Variant 2 explains your error.
You tried to parse hash and you added dots after any hash.
So when you got `null` or `*` you did string and got `.null` and `.*`

Comment: Thanks, very useful. However, both solutions still fail when navigating directly to a specific filter... I've now implemented solution 2 (though I would love to remove the dots from the url). Could you please have a look here? http://curaedis.chocolata.be/diensten#doelgroep=.grondeigenaar The error is the same as before: `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=doelgroep=.grondeigenaar]`

Comment: After much searching, I found the culprit. There was a conflicting script concerning the hash. Also, I've now used the latest version of Isotope... Thanks again for your response!